# Cannot set input and submit form in the middle of container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to align a  form in the middle of a container. Then set input bar to be as wide as half of that container. Here is my code.

```
<div id="sub" class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit.">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="email" class="form-control text-center" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center pt-3">
                        <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put your code into row?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div id="sub" class="col-6">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email submit.">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="email" class="form-control text-center" 
                          type="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center pt-3">
            <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```css
#sub{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  height:400px;
  align-items:center;
}

.form-wrapper{
  width:50%;
}

input{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <div id="sub" class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="form-wrapper">
                <form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit.">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="email" class="form-control text-center" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center pt-3">
                        <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```